# SQL Server 2005 Configuration manager services list empty

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have just installed SQL Server 2005 on a Windows 7 Home Edition system. I am planning to use the server from a .NET Application. Now I want to start the local database engine service.
I read [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/SQLDatabaseEngine07162008131940PM/SQLDatabaseEngine.aspx) and found out that SQL Server Configuration manager can canfigure database engines.

The problem is that when I open the SQL Server Configuration manager I see nothing in the 'SQL Server 2005 Services' and 'SQL Server 2005 Network Confiration' pages.

What should I do?

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but did you try to reinstall?  Are you sure you didn't install something like Embedded Or Compact edition?

Comment: I'm sure its not the Embedded or Compact edition. I have not tried to reinstall as I thought that maybe I'm missing something else.

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is that you might need to apply some service packs, AFAIK SQL Server 2005 is not supported on windows 7 without some service packs (not sure if it's supported at all).

Comment: Is the database server listed in the Services list?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: I have installed SQL Server 2005 SP 4 Using windows 7 update manager.

Comment: @PeterSchofield: Sorry, Where is the services list?

Comment: [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2009/05/14/sql-server-on-windows-7-rc-and-windows-server-2008-r2-rc.aspx) says there is support for windows 7 with SQL Server 2005 SP3.

Comment: @MostafaMahdieh Sorry, I'm out of ideas then.  BTW, in windows 7, just hit 'Start' and type 'services' in the search box and select 'view local services' in regards to what Peter Schofield was asking.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: Thanks for your help. I didn't find the service noted in the windows local services list. Regards

Comment: @MostafaMahdieh Then that means that it probably didn't install properly, I would reboot and do a re-install.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: Thanks! Reinstall Worked! I think I have cancelled one of the configuration questions in my first installation. I will mark your answer as correct if you add an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the simplest answer is the best answer: Reinstall.